# Are there any datasets regarding deaths due to lack of vaccination?

Tags: data-request, medical

I am looking for datasets concerning the topic "Vaccines" so I would be interested in datasets regarding the number of deaths (for each country, and maybe region) caused by lack of vaccination and vaccination coverage.

In particular, I am interested in the European (and Italian) situation. I searched on the Eurostat website but I didn't find anything about it. Is there an updated and well done site with this information?

I hope it's the right place to ask, if not, I apologize.

Comment: For vaccination coverage in germany you might want to look at http://www.vacmap.de/. It offers an interactive map and also a csv download (last button in the menu on the left)

Comment: @Phonolog Thanks for your advice. Do you have any advice to give me for the other countries?

Answer (score 1):

In the United States, each state health department has records on cause of death for each year.  You'll usually have to call the department to get the more detailed records, which include the icd-10 medical codes.  Those won't specify 'failure to vaccinate' AFAIK, but if you've got someone dying from, say, diptheria or whooping cough, it's a safe bet they weren't vaccinated.  Good luck.